# Do comments directed to moderators who acted to close a question reach them?

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked a question here on Meta which was closed by a moderator as a duplicate. I don't believe it is a duplicate and directed a comment to the moderator (using @) stating the difference between the two questions. Will that moderator, who did not comment under the post, receive a notice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

> Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified. **You can also notify a ♦ moderator who closed the question.**